# Auto submit form Using javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using a radio button to submit a form, only first record with the radio button is working other one does not

[example Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sjs96/q9a6v4ma/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/sjs96/q9a6v4ma/1/)

```
<form id="searchid" method="post" action="test.php">

    <label><input name="search" id="radio" type="radio">test1</label><br>
    <label><input name="search" id="radio" type="radio">test2</label><br>
    <label><input name="search" id="radio" type="radio">test3</label>

</form>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById("searchid");
document.getElementById("radio").addEventListener("click", function () {
    form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be only one `id` with same value. I suggest you to use class and instead of id's given in Code Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("searchid");  
    $('.radio').click(function(){
      form.submit();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchid" name='myForm' method="post" action="test.php">

                             <label><input name="search" class="radio" type="radio">test1</label><br>
                             <label><input name="search" class="radio" type="radio">test2</label><br>
                             <label><input name="search" class="radio" type="radio">test3</label>
                </form>
```

.

Comment: This is using jQuery, not Vanilla JS. You need to consider performance issues and avoid loading 70k file when you can use Vanilla JS for simple things such as this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have of multiple elements with same ID.

Use query selectors instead:

Try this:

```
var form = document.getElementById("searchid");
var currEl = document.querySelectorAll(".radio");
for (var i = 0; i < currEl.lenght; i++) {
    currEl[ i ].addEventListener("click", function () {
      form.submit();
});
}
```

Also,

Use different IDs for your radios. Having same ID will cause further issues and can impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use jquery  

var form = document.getElementById("searchid");
        $('input[type=radio]').on("click", function () {
          form.submit();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same id for the input tags.

```
<label><input name="search" id="radio1" type="radio">test1</label><br>
<label><input name="search" id="radio2" type="radio">test2</label><br>
<label><input name="search" id="radio3" type="radio">test3</label>
```

Change the JS code for those 3 ids,

```
var form = document.getElementById("searchid");
document.getElementById("radio1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});

document.getElementById("radio2").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});

document.getElementById("radio3").addEventListener("click", function () {
  form.submit();
});
```

For the dynamic radios, do it like in below.

create js function, only include the form submit,

```
var form = document.getElementById("searchid");
function myFunction() {
   form.submit();              
}
```

call that function with the onclick event,

```
<label><input name="search" type="radio" onclick = "myFunction()">test</label>
```

Comment: ok this works but i had one doubt , I call the records from the db then how can i change the id in js code. this is the code that i am use in php  <?php foreach($search_des as $sd) { ?>
                                
                                 <label><input name="search" id="radio" value="<?php echo $sd->des_category_id;?>" type="radio"><?php echo $sd->des_category_name;?></label>
                              <?php } ?>

Comment: Change the code as this and try, <?php $i = 0; foreach($search_des as $sd) { ?> <label><input name="search" id="radio<?php echo ++$i; ?>" value="<?php echo $sd->des_category_id;?>" type="radio"><?php echo $sd->des_category_name;?></label> <?php } ?>

Comment: I know this but how should i increment value in js.

Comment: If the radios are generate dynamically, you can do it in this way, remove ids from radios. create js function only include the form.submit part. call that function with the radio button using onclick event. I will edit the post.